# Cannot login to Careers Website

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

using the email/password combination. 
I tried clicking forgot passwd or creating new account.
Whatever I try gives me a 404.

https://openid.stackauth.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fLogOn
http://openid.stackauth.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fNotifyPassword

are all 404.

Comment: I have career profile at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/khivi which is the account I am trying to login to. From other posts, likely that account needs to be merged to stackexchange openid account. Though still cannot explain the 404s. I deleted cookies and tried different browsers.

Comment: Using Safari on OS X, when I do forgot password I get the same page back with url : http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/notifypassword?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Flogin&authMessage=NoAccountForReset&email=work%40khivi.com So it does seem I do not have a account. BUT I did get a email today from Careers at stackoverflow to the same email address (so I guess I do have a account) saying I have a message from compan X on Careers.

Comment: Can a moderator merge :merge stackoverflow.com/users/42669/khivi  and meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162763/khivi

Comment: those are two different accounts, they cannot be merged. Meta has a different account system than SO.

Answer (score 1):

You had an old careers account that used a claimid.com openID. I also found two new accounts you just created yesterday, they've all been merged. You can either log in using the claimID openID or your Stack Exchange username and password. Let us know if you run into any further issues.

Comment: Can you also merge : http://stackoverflow.com/users/42669/khivi and I think http://stackexchange.com/users/032495df-bc18-4147-8a30-13c1c27e2618?tab=accounts is the same

Comment: @khivi: There's nothing to merge -- one is your global Stack Exchange network profile, the other one is your Stack Overflow account.

Comment: I mean merge stackoverflow.com/users/42669/khivi to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/162763/khivi